# Running .jar in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, java

I have a .jar file which is console based. I would like to run it in Linux via SSH. So far I am able to run it and see the output.

However, after disconnecting and then reconnecting to the terminal, how can I access the output from the Java program again?

Comment: minecraft server remote administration?

Comment: ha nice guess!, though i play minecraft, not rly that ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want to leave the Java application running, even after you disconnect? If so, install [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html). `screen` allows you to create persistent sessions allowing you to keep programs/scripts running in their own session even after you log out of SSH.

If you're on Ubuntu or any Debian-based distro, installing `screen` is easy:

```
# apt-get install screen
```

To create a session:

```
$ screen -R sessionName
```

Start your Java application in the session and then when you are ready to detach and let it run in the background, type <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and then <kbd>D</kbd>. You can then safely disconnect from the SSH session.

To re-attach to the screen session, execute:

```
$ screen -r sessionName
```

The [Screen man pages](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) describe all of the other arguments and flags if you want to learn more.

---

If you simply want to save the output of the application for later reading, redirect `stdout` to a file:

```
$ java -jar my.jar > output.txt
```

Comment: your instructions were a breeze to follow through! Well written!

Comment: You are really Awesome man Mr. Rain... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

alternately you could also use Tmux, a more modern alternative to screen